# Java Spring Tomcat8: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: java, mysql, spring

This is driving me entirely nuts.
For the last 5 hours I have tried every possible combination to get connection to the db without success.

Here is what I did:

1) src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/context.xml

```
<Context>
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/zwoop_db"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        initialSize="5"
        maxActive="55"
        maxIdle="21"
        minIdle="13"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        validationInterval="34"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="233"
        username="root"
        password=""
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/zwoop_db?allowMultiQueries=true"
    />
</Context>
```

The frustrating thing is that this used to work, so there is nothing wrong with this file. I haven't changed a thing.
The db is properly running at the correct port:

[image]

The following bean is defined in the applicationContext:

```
    <bean id="restDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/zwoop_db" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Again, this should work, nothing has changed.

2) Added the mysql connector to the path: /Library/Tomcat/lib (Mac OSX)

[image]

3) Added the file zwoop-v001.xml to the path /Library/Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost manually. `copyXML` attribute on the context didn't work at all.

The stacktrace has been exactly the same for the last 5 hours, no matter what I tried. I haven't got a single clue what has changed, why it suddenly doesn't work anymore. I have gone through all related topics on every forum I've seen.

> Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2144)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2032)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Cannot create JDBC driver of
>   class '' for connect URL 'null' java.sql.SQLException: No suitable
>   driver    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2144)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2032)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.createUser(Unknown Source)    at
>   be.zwoop.entities.user.resource.UsersResource.createUserFromApplicationFormUrlEncoded(UsersResource.java:55)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>     at org.glasJul 06, 2016 8:35:29 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions WARN:
>   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null Jul 06, 2016 8:35:29 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions ERROR:
>   Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Help is welcome before I kill myself.

Comment: Did you try moving the mysql connector to $Catalina_base / lib directory

Comment: I added it to /Library/Tomcat/lib on Mac OSX (see updated question with screenshot).

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: Before you proceed, don't forget to copy the JDBC Driver's jar into $CATALINA_HOME/lib.

Comment: @gujralam Yes, but as indicated, it is copied to the correct location. Somehow he doesn't want to pick it up while it's obviously there. echo $CATALINA_HOME returns that path ~/Library/Tomcat. I could try another connector, but not sure if this will help...

Comment: i see that catalina_home is pointing to your home dir....but you have /Library/Tomcat under root dir from screenshot

Comment: @gujralam Yes, I noticed this too. Added to $CATALINA_HOME/lib as you requested but it didn't help. I've now temporarily solved it by adding the configuration to context.xml of Tomcat itself. I suppose that this isn't a solution as clean as adding it to the project, but at least I can continue my dev for the moment...

Comment: try to put context.xml inside META-INF (sibling of WEB-INF). Maybe is that the problem.

Comment: @OscarBcn Nope, same stacktrace. Surprises me, how these little things that should be so obvious, can be such a mystery :-/

Comment: Good to know your problem is resolved..you may refer to this tutorial for installation on mac https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat8/

Answer (score 0):

May be you could configure your jndi in web.xml

```html
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/zwoop_db</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

Then add configure in xml like this

```html
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
<property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/zwoop_db" />
```